# Why does foreach only execute once when param name isn't specified?

Tags: scala, loops

I want to execute a function three times. That function happens to return a string.

```
def doThingReturnString(): String = {
  println("Did a thing, returned a string.")
  "abcdef"
}

(1 to 3).foreach { n =>
  doThingReturnString()
}

(1 to 3).foreach {
  doThingReturnString()
}
```

I expect both loops to print three lines. Instead, the first loop prints three lines and the second loop prints one.

> Did a thing, returned a string.
>
> Did a thing, returned a string.
>
> Did a thing, returned a string.
>
> ---
>
> Did a thing, returned a string.

Why does naming the parameter cause the loop to only execute once?

Comment: In the first case, the method is being executed inside the `foreach`. On the second case, the function is just called before the `foreach` and _(for some reason I do not understand)_ the **String** that is returned is used as the function to call inside the `foreach`. Maybe ab implicit conversion that end up calling the `apply` method on the **String**.

Comment: Haha yowzer. `"abcdef"(2)` returns `c`, the character at index 2. Too much cleverness, or is there a use case for that functionality?

Comment: To which functionality are you referring to?

Comment: The ability to "call" a string. @HTNW pointed out the implicit conversion to `WrappedString`, used to access the string as a collection type. So I get the utility. Just surprised me in this instance.  :-)

Comment: A string is just a sequence of characters and has all corresponding methods - apply included.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`foreach` expects a function `Int => U` (where `U` can be "whatever"). Period. If you want to ignore the parameter, use an underscore.

```
(1 to 3).foreach { _ => doThingReturnString() }
```

When you write

```
(1 to 3).foreach { doThingReturnString() }
```

The braces act like parentheses

```
(1 to 3).foreach(doThingReturnString())
```

The argument for `foreach` must be `Int => U`, but here, it is a `String`. A `String` can be implicitly converted to an `Int => U`, because a `String` can [implicitly convert](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#wrapString(s:String):scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString) to [`WrappedString`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/WrappedString.html), which treats it as a collection type, specifically as a [`Seq[Char]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html), which can be upcast to a [`PartialFunction[Int, Char]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html) from indices to elements, which can be upcast to `Int => Char`. Thus, you've essentially written

```
val temp = doThingReturnString()
(1 to 3).foreach { i => temp.charAt(i) }
```

The reason for this behavior is that treating `Seq[A]`s as `PartialFunction[Int, A]`s is pretty sensible. Also sensible is being able to treat strings like the other collection types, so we have an implicit conversion to augment Java's `String` with Scala's collection architecture. Putting them together, so that `String`s turn into `Int => Char`s, produces somewhat surprising behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Let's change your expression to:

`(1 to 3).foreach { "abc"}`

Can you guess the result? It is

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3

If we change it to

`(1 to 3).foreach { "abcd"}`

the program executes without the exception. So, in case of your expression:

```
(1 to 3).foreach {
  doThingReturnString()
}
```

you: firstly execute `doThingReturnString()`, which returns a string `"abcdef"`. Then, for each number `i` in the range `1 to 3`, the compiler executes `"abcdef"(i)`.

As to why `(1 to 3).foreach { n => doThingReturnString() }` is seemingly treated differently from `(1 to 3).foreach { doThingReturnString() }`, the best explanation I know comes from the book *[Scala Puzzlers](http://scalapuzzlers.com/)* (p. 20; no affiliation with the authors):

> Since anonymous functions are often passed as arguments, it’s common
>   to see them surrounded by { ... } in code. It’s easy to think that
>   these curly braces represent an anonymous function, but instead they
>   delimit a block expression: one or multiple statements, with the last
>   determining the result of the block.

Comment: The curly-brace syntax is cool, but plays with my OO mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
object Intercept { def apply[T](v: T) { println(s"Intercept called with value '$v'") } }
(1 to 3).foreach { Intercept[Int] } // or just (1 to 3) foreach Intercept[Int]
```

, that outputs:

```
Intercept called with value '1'
Intercept called with value '2'
Intercept called with value '3'
```

And consider this

```
(1 to 3).foreach { println("start"); println }
```

that prints

```
start
1
2
3
```

vs

```
(1 to 3).foreach { x => println("start"); println(x) }
```

that prints

```
start
1
start
2
start
3
```

So,

- if anonymous function is provided (elem =>), everything gets executed
- if block is provided, then foreach acts on the result of the block (the last line) invoking 'apply(_)' on it, with the exception where _ is used.